# Modify RDS instance from AWS Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I have a running Amazon RDS instance in AWS.

1. I want to know can I create lambda expression that expression will change RDS instance accessibility from private to public?
2. Can I create lambda expression that will take native backup as AWS described in [Perform Native Backups of an Amazon RDS Instance That's Running SQL Server](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/native-backup-rds-sql-server/)?

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use [modify_db_instance](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/rds.html#RDS.Client.modify_db_instance) method.
2. You can use [create_db_snapshot](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/rds.html#RDS.Client.create_db_snapshot) method.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @anton.uspehov.By your first reply I can set accessibility to the public to private. But I have a doubt related to your second answer. By this, I can only take snapshots this will not full fill my need. I want to create a **(.bak)** file that described by aws in their native backup documentation.

Comment: Oh, for native backup you only need to run the query from Lambda.
For example with psycopg2 (Postgresql lib for python), it depends on your stack.